# Having separate or combined Blog and main application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Should two applications such as, for example, a custom company blog and twitter clone application be combined into one application?  I would have the same navbar in each and the blog would have OAuth as well as being able to use users from the twitter clone for comments.  Besides those two similarities everything else is different.

So should it be one rails application or two distinct applications since in the end they do different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rails Engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) to extract common functionality between two Rails apps, this includes the entire Rails stack (models, controllers, views, helpers, etc...). This is a common approach to dealing with the ole' "two apps that are kind of the same but not really the same" problem.